# Show that $ y''+\tan y\cdot(y')^2=0$ when $y=\tan^{-1}(\sin h x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried solving it in this manner:
$$\tan y=\sin h x$$
Differentiate with respect to $x$:
\begin{align*}
\sec^2y_1&=h \cos hx\\
sec^2 y\frac{d y}{dx}&=h \cos hx\\
\frac{d y}{dx}&=\frac{h\cos hx}{\sec^2y}\\
y_1&=\frac{h\cos hx}{1+\tan^2y}\\
y_1+y_1(\tan^2y)=h\cos hx
\end{align*}
Differentiate with respect to $x$:
\begin{align*}
y_2+2y_1\tan y\sec^2y+y_2\tan^2y=-h^2\sin hx \\
y_2=\frac{-(h^2\sin hx+2y_1\tan y \sec^2y)}{1+\tan^2y}.
\end{align*}
This as far as I have gotten.

Comment: Are you sure it's $\sin hx$ (sine of $hx$) and not $\sinh x$ (hyperbolic sine of $x$)?

Comment: Are you sure $h$ is a constant?  Because it looks like you're dealing with hyperbolic sine.

Comment: In the question they have neither mentioned "constant" or "hyperbolic sine".i don't know what is hyperbolic sine, so i assumed "h" to be a constant.Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the equation is $y=\tan^{-1}(\sinh x)$, where $\sinh x$ is the hyperbolic sine of $x$, then we can compute $y'$ with the chain rule:
$$
y'=\frac{1}{1+\sinh^2 x}\cosh x=\frac{1}{\cosh^2x}\cosh x=\frac{1}{\cosh x},
$$
recalling that $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$. Thus
$$
y''=-\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh^2x}
$$
and the stated relation follows immediately.

The hyperbolic sine and cosine are defined by
$$
\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2},\qquad \cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}.
$$
From the definition it's easy to compute
$$
\sinh'x=\cosh x,\quad \cosh'x=\sinh x,\quad \cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1.
$$

Comment: how is $sinh'x=coshx$ and$cosh'x=sinhx$ and what does "$sinh'x$ or$sinh'x$ "signify??

Comment: @Nikhil01 With $\sinh'x$ I mean the derivative; since the derivatives of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ are $e^x$ and $-e^{-x}$ the stated formulas follow. The hyperbolic sine and cosine are quite useful when doing integrals.

Comment: Thank you .i understand it now  :).